# google chrome extention send email site block of dns

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to build an extension on Google Chrome which functions will be forwarding address illicit websites that email to parents, which prohibited it site address using DNS Nawala or something similar, with the extension prevents the expected negative impact of the use of the internet.
What are the steps that I did in building this extension ?
Thank you.

Comment: These sorts of questions never yield a good response as you're asking people to provide detailed methodology without providing any code samples or ideas. If you give a little, people will give back.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad "how do I create my entire project" question, but I'll try to give you some broad advice:

An extension alone will not be enough for this. You're going to need a web service as well. You'll likely need to divide the project into two parts:

1. A Chrome extension that monitors the websites a person visits. You can do this by using the [Tab API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html). Simply look at each site the user has visited and if they visit any of the illicit sites on a blacklist, take an action, probably by making an API call to the web service mentioned below.
2. You're almost certainly going to need to use a web service developed with a scripting language like PHP or Java, or something similar. This web service would take care of sending the emails to parents. If we're just talking about sending an email to one parent than this service could be quite simple. The extension would tell the web service to send an email when an illicit site is visited, and that's about it. If you're talking about a commercial project then this service would probably need to be a full fledged website that allows parents to sign up for these emails.

Again, this is a very broad question, and generally speaking Stackoverflow is more for asking specific programming questions. But hopefully this will get you moving in the right direction at least, so you can come back and ask more specific questions. :-)